# power automate desktop の 「ファイルの移動」で空白を含むファイル名のファイルを移動させたい。

Tags: windows, rpa

power automate desktopの「ファイルを移動」でファイル名に空白を含むファイルを移動させたいです。
空白を含まない場合は正しく移動できるのですが、空白を含むと駄目みたいです。
パス名をシングルクォートやダブルクォートでくくるのも試したのですがうまく動かないです。

どうすればファイル名に空白を含むファイルを移動させられるでしょうか？

Comment: Power Automate Desktop Ver 2.40.157.24023で半角スペースを含むファイルを移動したところ意図通りに動作して移動しました。
スペースが全角になっていたり、末尾に余分なスペースが入っていたりはしないでしょうか。

Comment: ファイル名の先頭にピリオドがついてるはずのファイルだったのですが、なぜかダウンロードした際にそのピリオドが外れていました。それでファイル名がズレていたのが移動できない原因だったようです。失礼しました。